# How to pass data using submit() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to post data from one page to another using javascript post method?

Below is the javascript I am using..

In  *test1.asp* page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Service_Add(Data_ID,Data_Type)
{
var Data_ID=Data_ID;
var Data_Type=Data_Type;

document.miformulario.submit();// Here I want to pass data like "Submit(Data_ID,Data_Type)"
}
</script>
```

I want to post "`Data_ID`" and "`Data_Type`" to *test2.asp* page

Answer (score 3):

To pass data when you submit a form, you have to include that data in a form input field (hidden, visible, doesn't matter).

Comment: problem is test1.asp input field names are not constant

Comment: xmlHttp.open("POST","test2.asp",true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
   xmlHttp.send(params);

this is the type i using in javascript/ ajax

Comment: there is some thing like this in javascript

Comment: You aren't submitting a Javascript form. You're submitting an HTML form using Javascript (and that's the only way to do it). To send data in an HTML form, you need the data in an HTML input.

Answer (score 3):

You can add hidden fields in your HTML form like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="Data_ID">
<input type="hidden" id="Data_Type">
```

and then set the values in your javascript function and then submit (?)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Service_Add(Data_ID,Data_Type)
{

document.getElelementByID("Data_ID").value=Data_ID;
document.getElelementByID("Data_Type").value=Data_Type;

document.miformulario.submit();

}
</script>
```

Comment: The idea was right, but the code didn't work. The way for modifying the value was the problem. It worked for me (with jQuery): `$('input[name="variable"]').val(true);`